# Saving within nested loops with promises

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parse-platform, save, promise

I want to save an object called singleInfo in a column for qualifying parseObjects as shown below. The code below chooses the right objects to save to but it only saves data intended for the last object to all of the objects.  I'm pretty sure it is a problem with how I'm doing the loops. I thought the promises would resolve this.  I used a similar promise pattern in the past that provided good results but it's not working this time. I think it has something to do with the nested loops as before I only used this patter on a single loop.

```
var func = function(){
    var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
    var array = [];
    var pairs = [parseObject, parseObject, parseObject];
    var a = pairs.length;
    while(a--){
        var pair = pairs[a];
        var singles = [obj, obj, obj, obj, obj];
        var b = singles.length;
        while(b--){
            var single = singles[b];
            if(single.value === pair.get('value')){
                var singleInfo = {news: single.news, time: pair.get('time')}
                query.get(pair.id, {
                    success: function (goal){
                        goal.set('newColumn', singleInfo);
                        array.push(goal.save());
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        promise.then(function(){
            return Parse.Promise.when(array);
        }
```

Comment: Can we see your Object? It could be that your always setting a "New Column" to the value singleInfo, wouldn't it be better to have a "Column" with an array in it, and push items to the end?

Comment: Dean, could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean by 'see my Object'. Do you mean parseObject, singleInfo or the root of query.get? I'm also not clear what you mean by "wouldn't it be better to have a "Column" with an array in it, and push items to the end".  I don't think your second suggestion makes sense as there is is only the one object, singleInfo going into newColumn.  There will never be more than one object there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

I did not completely understand your code( missing brackets), but I assumed the problem was this line `return Parse.Promise.when(array);`, bec `array` gets updated on success callback, so `Promise.when` might operate on incorrect array,

I have taken that line out of while loop( for `a`), promisified the `query.get`, haven't tested it, hope it works and what you were expecting...

```
var func = function(){
    var array = [];
    var pairs = [parseObject, parseObject, parseObject];
    var a = pairs.length;
    while(a--){
        var pair = pairs[a];
        var singles = [obj, obj, obj, obj, obj];
        var b = singles.length;
        while(b--){
            var single = singles[b];
            if(single.value === pair.get('value')){
                var singleInfo = {news: single.news, time: pair.get('time')};
                array.push(pGet(pair.id, singleInfo));
            }
        }
    }

    return Parse.Promise.when(array).then(function(){
        var promises = [];
        for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
            promises.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
    });
}              

function pGet(id, info){        
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    query.get(id, {
        success: function (goal){
            goal.set('newColumn', info);
            promise.resolve(goal.save());
        }
    });

}
```

---

old answer

<strike>simplest way to solve it would be, wrap it by an anonymous function....</strike>

```
           ...
           var singleInfo = {news: single.news, time: pair.get('time')}
           (function(id, info){
               query.get(id, {
                   success: function (goal){
                   goal.set('newColumn', info);
                   array.push(goal.save());
                   }
               });
           })(pair.id, singleInfo);
           ...
```

Comment: My test data says that it should be returning two results but I'm only getting one result to the wrong Parse.Object.  Could you elaborate a bit on your example?  Is there something I'm missing? with var singleInfo above the anonymous function I get: object is not a function with it below it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: F-IN brilliant answer. It works like a charm! I stewed on that for hours (I've seriously only been coding for 3 months - save for stack overflow and occasional visits with a buddy totally self guided . . . Parse and Angular are sweet but the documentation leaves a little to be desired. Anyhow you are the man!!!! I'm only sad that I can't give you more props!

Comment: Would you answer me one more question if I posted it?

Comment: @middo22 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294790/filtering-arrays-of-complex-objects-with-loops

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73904/discussion-between-mido22-and-rashadb).