# Filtering arrays of complex objects with loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have two arrays of complex nexted objects that I'm looking for qualifying values within using loops and if statements as seen below.  When I find a qualifying object, I need to filter that object out during the next go around of the loop. I'm trying to do that with an array as you can see here but it isn't working as the array starts over during each iteration of the loop. The following version is a simplified version of my code.

I want to update the values in array2 based on the if statement so that those values are not repeated in the nested loop. Instead my emptyArray remains empty instead of adding values from the array2 as elements of array2 are equal to elements of array.

To be clear, right now emptyArray remains empty and never filters array2. I'd like to see emptyArray collect value 2 at the start of the outer loop's second iteration then I'd like to see emptyArray collect value 4 at the start of the 4th iteration of the outer loop.

I'd want to filter each of these values from array2 as they become part of emptyArray so that they do not set off the if statement during the 6th and 8th iterations of the outer loop. I imagine that emptyArray = [2, 4] and array2 = [6, 8, 10] when the loops are finished.

Bottom line, I need emptyArray to collect the qualifying values and pass them back to var array2 for filtering as the loop processes.  Remember this is a simplified version of the arrays, and underscore based solution would be very complicated for me to implement or for you to successfully suggest without much more detail.

My code:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var emptyArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     var something = array[i];
     var array2 = _.without(array2, emptyArray);
     for (a = 0; a < array2.length; a++){
         var value = array2[a];
          if(something === value){
              emptyArray.push(value);
              break;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Ah.. can you be succinct?

Comment: @Amit Joki, I tried to be succinct with a similar question but I was told I left out to much detail. It's really hard for me to articulate it well. Sorry. Bottom line, each time emptyArray.push(value) happens it should carry through the loop but right now it resets during each iteration of the loop.

Comment: can you show an example of expected result? something to help understand purpose better than your prose?

Comment: "I imagine that emptyArray = [2, 4] and array2 = [6, 8, 10] when the loops are finished." from next to last paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code, but the reason why you think that push isn't working is because you are overriding your array2 inside the loop.

The push never gets called because your for loop sees an empty array2 when you are doing `var array2 = _.without(array2, emptyArray);`

Basically `var array2 = _.without(array2 /* this is empty, you just overrode it in this scope */, emptyArray);` will always result in an empty array and your for loop will exit because length is array2.length === 0 from the start.

Also, you want to use `_.difference` instead of `_.without`

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var emptyArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var something = array[i];
  array2 = _.difference(array2, emptyArray);
  for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    var value = array2[j];
    if (something === value) {
      emptyArray.push(value);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log("array2",array2);
console.log("emptyArray", emptyArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

```
array2 [6, 8, 10]
emptyArray [2, 4]
```

Comment: I see your answer but I don't see how you changed my original code save for the difference vs. without reference which doesn't matter as long as emptyArray remains empty at the start of each loop.

Comment: notice there is no longer a "var" before array2 inside the first loop.

Comment: yes, i noticed that and made that correction also. how are you getting emptyArray [2, 4, 2, 4]? i'm getting []

Comment: also, using without does not work because you have an array of values, without takes varargs, not an array. Use _.difference if you want to check against an array.

Comment: thanks for that insight! i was wondering what the difference is. they look the same in the documentation.

Comment: open the browser dev console  and click run code snippet in my answer. you should see the results of the console.log in your log. The only other thing i changed with your code is i declared the loop variables i and j. `for (var i`... `for (var j`...

Comment: I see that in my console, thanks - I always wondered how to make that thing work smh. It still doesn't work in my console in my environment though it works perfectly in your's.  In my environment, the answer I just posted works

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var emptyArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var something = array[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    var value = array2[j];
    if (something === value) {
      array2 = _.without(array2, value);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is all you wanted, you just need `array2 = _.difference(array2, array1)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nfwL0vxj/ mido22 got it to work like you also. _difference(array2, array) won't work because of the conditionals and the fact that it needs to carry forward. @DTing, the key thing was 'var'. I needed to drop that to make it work in my environment.  That's why you got the green check! I do appreciate your help, you provided a number of helpful insights!